# ld: library not found for -lqt

Tags: matlab, qt, mex

When I tried to compile these files on matlab on my mac

```
mex -O obj/compute_error.o obj/model_analysis.o obj/mesh_run.o obj/reporting.o obj/colormap.o obj/xalloc.o obj/mesh.o obj/ScreenWidget.o obj/TextWidget.o obj/Error3DViewerWidget.o obj/ColorMapWidget.o obj/Lighted3DViewerWidget.o obj/Basic3DViewerWidget.o obj/InitWidget.o obj/moc_Basic3DViewerWidget.o obj/moc_Lighted3DViewerWidget.o obj/moc_Error3DViewerWidget.o obj/moc_ScreenWidget.o obj/moc_InitWidget.o obj/moc_ColorMapWidget.o lib/lib3d.a -L/usr/local/opt/qt/lib -L/opt/X11/lib/ -lqt -lGL -lGLU -lpthread -lXmu -lXext -lX11 -lm -lz   -output bin/meshx
```

I got this error saying that the library is not found

```
Error using mex
ld: library not found for -lqt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I successfully installed qt5.9.0 using brew and inside my /usr/local/opt/qt/lib has frameworks [frameworks inside /usr/local/opt/qt/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGwZm.jpg)

I don't know the problem is caused because of missing frameworks or incorrect installation of qt or other issues.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe MATLAB does not know where QT is

Comment: Flag `-lqt` is for old qt (version 3?). For current version, you should use `-lQt5Core -lQt5Gui -lQt5Widgets`. Depends on your code, maybe you also need to link against other Qt modules.